# ng-model not working in a table

Tags: angularjs

I have a ng-model(comment) inside a text area that is inside or a table.  When I print out the scope I keep getting undefined.  Here is my code

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Message</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="message in messages">
            <td ng-bind="message.message"> </td>
            <td ng-bind="message.user"> </td>

            <td> <button ng-if= "message.user == name" 
                ng-click="delete(message._id)">Delete</button></td>
                <td><textarea ng-model = "comment"></textarea></td>
            <td><button ng-click="enter_comment(message._id, name)">Add Comment</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is my controller

```
app.controller('welcomeController', ['$scope', '$location', 'welcomeFactory',function($scope, $location, welcomeFactory){
    index = function(){
        welcomeFactory.get_name(function(returned_data){
            $scope.name = returned_data.data.user

        })
    }
    getMessages = function(){
        welcomeFactory.get_messages(function(returned_data){
            $scope.messages = returned_data.data.message
        })
    }
    index();
    getMessages();
    $scope.enter_message = function(){
        welcomeFactory.new_message($scope.message, $scope.name, function(sendUser){
            console.log(sendUser)
            index();
            getMessages();
        })
    }
    $scope.enter_comment = function(message_id, name){
        console.log($scope.comment)
        welcomeFactory.new_comment(message_id, name, $scope.comment ,function(sendMessage){
            index();
            getMessages();
        })
    }

}]);
```

Is there a workaround? ng-model works when not in a table, but when in a table it does not,

Comment: what does your controller look like?

Comment: @Kai, I just added the controller

Comment: Try removing the spaces? `ng-model="comment"`?  Not sure if that would help but can't see anything else wrong

Comment: `ng-repeat` creates child scopes, so `comment` will be set in a different scope than your controller's scope.

Comment: @user1620220 -- shouldn't matter, as long as `comment` isn't re-declared inside the child scopes it should work

Comment: @tymeJV it absolutely matters, just tested in plunker and it is setting the comment in the child scope.

Comment: It is careless to say ngModel does not work in a table. It certainly does. Your code is much more likely to be the problem than Angular which has been verified to work correctly again and again by countless people. You should provide a plunker that demonstrates the behavior you describe.

Comment: That's some interesting code... You realize that `index` and `getMessages` are now global functions, right? You'll want to use `var index = function() {...` if you don't want to expose them everywhere. You'll want to use `$parent.comment` as the target of `ng-model`, or, perhaps better, use `ng-controller` and make `comment` a property of the controller instead of using `$scope`.

Comment: @user1620220 - Yep, you're right, and at second glance it's obvious.

Answer (score 0):

looking at code $scope.messages is not an array but  in html you are trying to iterate over messages

also try console.log(returned_data.data.message) is it displaying any value?